# Missing dispatcher-servlet.xml in spring mvc project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I created a Spring mvc project in Spring tool suit. I am following a YouTube tutorial video and the author of the video refers to some text being added to dispatcher-servlet.xml, but the dispatcher-servlet.xml was not created when I created the Spring project. Why is that? Can it be called something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are several way to create simple spring web project. Some way i know is:

1. From eclipse (STS) create dynamic web project/and put the spring lirary to it.
2. Form STS File/New/Maven project (org.apache.maven.archetypes)/ fill group id , artifact id v.v..
3. From STS File/New /Spring Project/ Simple Spring Web Maven.
4. Spring Roo command `web mvc setup`

Not belong how to create the project ,after create it we always have the file web.xml

content of web.xml similarly like this

```
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<!-- The most important thing to understand is that there are 2 layers of application contexts,
 and they each have default XML files to load beans from
 1.Servlet Application Context
 2.Root application context
  -->

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <!-- 
    The Each Spring DispatcherServlet defined in the web.xml file gets its own application context. 
    If there is a Root application context (i.e. if a ContextLoaderListener is defined), then 
    that will be the parent of the servlet context and the beans will be available for use in 
    the servlet context(s). By default, DispatcherServlet loads beans from the file
     /WEB-INF/<servlet-name>-servlet.xml -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>  
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!--The Root application context is created 
        when you specify a ContextLoaderListener in your web.xml file. If you don't 
        specify a listener, then there will be no Root context (which is valid). 
        It allows you to define beans that will be available to all the servlet
         contexts.REMEMBER: This context is OPTIONAL, and will only be created if 
         you specify a ContextLoaderListener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

the declaration

```
<init-param>
       <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
       <param-value>WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

is position of dispatcher-servlet xml configuration file. If missing this declaration, the default will be the file name dispatcher-servlet.xml in direcrory webapp (or WebContent). If missing dispatcher-servlet.xml , don't worry, just create the file in there. We can change the name and position of dispathcher servlet xml config file by put this declation to web.xml file as above

```
<init-param>
           <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
           <param-value>WEB-INF/example/funny.xml</param-value>
 </init-param>
```

think it could help